# How to check if a controller exists using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, controller

I'm writing a plugin for my Zend Framework app and want to do a quick check to see if a controller exists. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the isDispatchable - Method of the front controller by passing it a Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract instance.

```
if( $front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($testRequest) )  
{  
    //things to do
}
```

Comment: Cheers, you gave me the solution in the time it took to make a cuppa tea!

Comment: where we put this code? I'm at boostrap, I have some route, I need to check if controller is not exist, then add some new route.